# smarty php anchor link not working

Tags: php, html, anchor, smarty

Hi I was wondering if you could help me with an issue where with my smarty php code won't work.  The problem is the anchor tag containing all of the code in this section won't actually surround it when it is outputted to the web page.

```
<a href="mylink"> //the link that does not actually work/surround the code below when outputed
    <div class="row" {if $smarty.section.pm_loop.last}style="border:none;"{/if}>
        <div class="f-right" style="padding-right: 35px">
            <a href='UserMessagesNew.php?pm_id={$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}'>{$Application659}</a><br/>
            <a href='UserMessagesView.php?pm_id={$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}&task=delete'>{$Application660}</a><br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name='message_{$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}' value='1' style="margin:0; height:15px; width:15px;"/>
        </div>
        <a class="f-left" href="UserMessagesView.php?pm_id={$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}"><img src="{$pms[pm_loop].pm_user->user_photo('./images/nophoto.gif')}" class='img' width="92px" alt="{$pms[pm_loop].pm_user->user_info.user_username} {$Application500}"></a>
        <a href="#" class="msg-info-c">
            <div class="msg-user-re"><b><a href="UserMessagesView.php?pm_id={$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}">{$pms[pm_loop].pm_user->user_info.user_username}</a></b></div>
            <a href="UserMessagesView.php?pm_id={$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}"><div class="msg-datet">{$datetime->cdate("`$setting.setting_timeformat` `$setting.setting_dateformat`", $datetime->timezone($pms[pm_loop].pm_date, $global_timezone))}</div></a>
            <a href="UserMessagesView.php?pm_id={$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}"><div class="user-msg-c">{$pms[pm_loop].pm_body|truncate:100|choptext:75:"<br>"}</div></a>
        </a>
    </div>
</a>
```

The output looks like this:

```
<a href="mylink"></a>
<div class="row">

     rest of content inside here

</div>
```

Comment: While you can place block elements in `a` in HTML5, you can _not_ __nest__ `a` elements.

Comment: is there any solution to this? because it confuses me quite a bit.

Comment: Solution to _what_ …?

Comment: The a tag does not surround the div in the output when I need that link to do so

Comment: basically what am trying to say is there another way to put a link rather then nesting an a tag because the a tag does not work

Comment: You can only either use JavaScript to react on a click on the area outside of the inner links, or place a link _behind_ the content using CSS positioning. (But this is not good UX in general – the user does most likely not expect that certain parts of a piece of content are links to special targets, and clicking just slightly next to those links will take them someplace else …)

Comment: the problem with the javascript would be the link is in a smarty format which is                                                       a href="UserMessagesView.php?pm_id{$pms[pm_loop].pm_id}"

Comment: _“the link is in a smarty format”_ – no idea what that’s supposed to mean. If you have the URL as a single value, then outputting it as value of a `href` attribute is no different then outputting it as a JS text literal.

Comment: oh yeah my bad I forgot for some reason, should know more than that thanks, if you want to post that as a answer i can accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can place block elements in `a` in HTML5, you can *not* **nest** `a` elements.

You can only either use JavaScript to react on a click on the area outside of the inner links, or place a link *behind* the content using CSS positioning.

(But this is not good UX in general – the user does most likely not expect that certain parts of a piece of content are links to special targets, and clicking just slightly next to those links will take them someplace else …)